# python tkinter application folder structure

Tags: python, tkinter, directory-structure

I started to do some python (python 3 if its matters) and I'm wondering how do I do folder structure (where do I put tkiner files, network files, main file, config file (user input)?)

I guess writing everything in single file is terrible, so how do I organize my folder(s)?

Comment: you can structure your application however you want... and then have the files [import each other as modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). although I am probably misunderstanding your question.

Comment: is there any best practice, some guide that most of devs are using, something like blueprint for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use something like [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) to organise and provide a template for your project.